# Can't access uploaded file data in POST request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, dropzone.js

something weird happend even though I do everything as usaual, maybe you will spot my mistake.

I am using dropzone.js plugin for file upload and then I have a controller that handles saving this file, however in controller I can't actually see the file data.

Pre-requisits:
php.ini is OK
POST requestis OK
Running on localhost (XAMP)

This is a minimalistic example I ended up with (still not working)

Front-end

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')       
    <!-- Change /upload-target to your upload address -->
    <form action="{{url('attachment')}}" class="dropzone"></form>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.css">
@endsection
```

ROUTE

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('attachment','AttachmentController@Save');
});
```

Controller

```
class AttachmentController extends Controller
{
    public function Save()
    {
        var_dump(Input::get());
    }
}
```

POST request

```
-----------------------------18028969725576
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="3.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

ÿØÿá�Exif��II*������������ÿì�Ducky�����(��ÿámhttp://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/�<?xpacket begin="ï»¿"
 [...]
```

Response

```
array(0) {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($_FILES)` ? Informations about an uploaded file is available in the `$_FILES` superglobal variable.

Comment: Yes, I tired most of php and laravel stuff like Input::file() and $_POST. Still thank you for suggestion, much appreciated. :)

Comment: Don't you need to work with `Input::file` or `Request::file` in stead of `Input::get`? Also try adding `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your form tag (not sure if dropzone will pick this up, but normal uploads require it iirc).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$request->file('file')` instead of `Input::get()`. As an example, try the snippet below to save it in your server of path `storage/exports`.

Make sure you create the `exports` folder in your storage folder

```
class AttachmentController extends Controller
{
    public function Save(Request $request)
    {
                $request->file('file')->move(
                     storage_path('exports'), 'uploadedFile.jpg'
                );

    }
}
```